# Nature of $u_n(x)=\sqrt{a_1(x)+\sqrt{a_2(x)+\sqrt{\dots+\sqrt{a_n(x)}}}},a_n(x)=x^{2^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursive-algorithms

In a question posed in this forum [convergence of $u_n=\sqrt{a_1+\sqrt{a_2+\sqrt{\dots+\sqrt{a_n}}}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921755/convergence-of-u-n-sqrta-1-sqrta-2-sqrt-dots-sqrta-n)
, the author proved that if $a_n=\lambda^{2^n}$ then $a_n$ tends to $\phi\lambda,\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. Now, if we take $a_n(x)=x^{2^n}$, does the sequence converges to $\phi x$ and how to show that? Thank you in advance.

Comment: ...isn't that literally just a replacement of the variable $\lambda$ with $x$?

Comment: I have no way to prove that since the recursive sequence depend of $a_n$ and the term with $x^{2^n}$

Comment: Are you asking how OP proved that $u_n \rightarrow \phi\lambda$ from $a_n = \lambda^{2^n}$, or are you asking how to show that $u_n \rightarrow x^{2^n}$ given that result?

Comment: The second result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the OP wants to know why if $a_n=x^{2^n}$ the series $u_n$ conveges to $\phi x$, something that is not proven in the linked question but taken for granted.

To do this, consider the following steps. Take first $x=1$, so that $a_n=1$ for each $n$.

(1) When $x=1$, the recursive relation is true:

$u_0=1, u_{n+1}=\sqrt{1+u_n}$

Suppose a limit exists $l$. Than it will satisfy (why?) $l=\sqrt{1+l}$

(2) To prove the limit exists, consider visually the function $f(x)=\sqrt{1+x}$ for positive $x$ and its intersections with the line $y=x$. Can you plot the succession of points $u_n$ ? In order to formalize the intuition show that:

$0\le x\le\phi \rightarrow 0\le f(x)\le\phi $

This shows that the sequence is bounded. Since it is increasing, it has a limit.

(3) Now change to $x>1$. Let's call $u_n(x)$ the new $u_n$. Can you show that $u_n(x)=x u_n(1)$ at a fixed $n$ ? (check small $n$ to develop an intuition) Than just take the limit of this relation and exploit the result you already found for $x=1$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Then if we take $\lambda=\psi(x)^{2^{n}}$ we obtain the convergence to $\phi\psi(x)$.

Comment: Yes $\lambda$, or $x$ in my answer, is a dummy variable and can be substituted as $x\rightarrow \psi(x)$ if needed